# My widget create with OpenComponents doesn't use is javascript logic client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, open-components

I try to create a widget using react and OpenComponents and when I try to use my widget **client-side** the react part load correctly but the javascript logic doesn't work.

I look to the console and I have no error message. Before to use **react** I try with **handlebars** and I have the issue. I have also try to use it **server-side** it work perfectly.

**This is my index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycss.css">
    <title>Widget</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var oc = {conf: {debug: true}};
</script>
<script src="http://localhost:3030/oc-client/client.js"></script>
<script src="js/header.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<oc-component href="http://localhost:3030/mywidget"></oc-component>
</body>
</html>
```

**my component**

```
<script src="{{path}}js/app.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="magnet"></div>
<script src="{{path}}js/index.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**my package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mywidget",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "repository": "",
  "oc": {
    "files": {
      "data": "server.js",
      "template": {
        "src": "template.html",
        "type": "handlebars"
      },
      "static":["js"]
    }
  }
}
```

**and my server.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports.data = function(context, callback){

  callback(null, {
    path:context.staticPath,
    init: {
      to: context.params.to || 7015400,
      from: context.params.from || 8727100,
      depart: context.params.depart || '01/01/1900',
      return: context.params.return || '01/01/1901',
      point_of_sale: context.params.point_of_sale || "XXXXX"
    }
  });
};
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to put some efforts here: https://github.com/opentable/oc/issues/299

In any case (Just to keep the Stack Overflow question up-to-date) - this is a quite common scenario. While a list of script tags are downloaded in parallel in modern browsers, the execution will most likely happen in the right order. So, A.js will execute first, B.js will execute after, and if B depends on A you will be fine.

In the client-side, when injecting the same thing in the DOM, things can be a bit different. To guarantee execution in the right order, in OC you can try the following:

Replace

```
<script src="a.js"></script>
<script src="b.js"></script>
```

With

```
<script>
  //Following is to guarantee this works if either this is client-side rendered
  // or server-side rendered - so if the oc namespace is available already or not
  window.oc = window.oc || {};
  oc.cmd = oc.cmd || [];

  // Here you require the 2 files in the right order
  oc.cmd.push(function(){
    oc.require('a.js', function(){
      oc.require('b.js', function(){
        console.log('now all should be ok');
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Obviously you can use any other dependency loading system as an alternative approach, but this should quite surely make the client-side execution work in the same way it does on the server.